# Correlation between number of features and number of parameters in a CNN

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm beginning to learn deep learning and I'm wondering if there is a correlation between the number of features of the input and the number of parameters in a CNN.

I'm actually looking for a way to select the optimal number of parameters in the networks. For instance in a network with only Dense layer, the number of parameters are adjusted depending on the value of the loss function, is it the same for a CNN ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert. But still, want to answer it.

I think there is some correlation between the number of features of the input and the number of parameters in a CNN. More The number of features, the more complex structure of your CNN should be, to get more accuracy. The complex architecture means more parameters. so this is how it is related. As features increase your network have to learn more complex things, that means more complex architecture.

To find the optimum number of params, I think it is a trial and error approach. You try different settings. Find out which works best for you in terms of both accuracy and optimum params. Hope my answers will help.